# What is behind this node scope error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, request

Here I have a node module I was working on. Previously it was just many nested functions. I wanted to improve the code, so instead wrote out all the functions, then called them all at the bottom in order. A weird thing happened, and not I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`.

```
var User = require( '../models/userModel' ),
    ...

exports.add = function ( req, res ) {

    function getVideoId ( req, callback ) {
        videoId = URL.parse( req.query.url ).query.slice(-11)
        callback( videoId )
    }

    ...


    getVideoId( req, function() {
        ...
            ...
                ...
                    ...
                        ...

                            return res.json( "Done." )
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should look at promises instead of callback hell ?

Comment: I'm with @adeneo on this one. If this is asynchronous code you really want to use [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/). What you have here is one of those "Pyramid of Doom" anti-patterns. More information on the ES6 standard, which works out of the box in [iojs](http://iojs.org/), is available through the ever-useful [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I have started doing that. Was up last night writing yet a third version of this code and not having it work as described. One thing at a time.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging here. What does `req` have populated when called by `getVideoId`? It's also worth noting that declaring and then immediately calling functions within a function a somewhat dubious optimization. You might want to declare your functions first, external to that, and then use them in the final function you're exporting.

Comment: @tadman Re: declaring functions outside of the export; yes, I did that, but moved them in to try solve this scope problem. When I do a `console.log( req.query )` I see a json object with `url: 'my-url` in it.

Comment: Looks like I was calling the `getVideoId` function in two different places and the first time was fine, but not the second time for more obvious scoping reasons. I was up too late I think.

Comment: @adeneo I think I'm struggling a lot more with scope and whatnot with promises now.

Answer (score 1):

Your scoping changed when you de-nested the functions. Since you were declaring a function inside another, the scope was maintained. So while inside nested-function 3, you could use all the values of nested-functions 1 and 2!

Comment: I do not think this is the root of the problem.  `req` is still in scope, it's the `query` property of `req` that is undefined.  If it were a scoping error, `req` wouldn't be defined.

Comment: I had a hard time telling the code flow from the original question. Like what line had the error, and that line's context. Maybe the `url` property was on a different undefined variable? I do agree with you, but if the only thing that changed from "working" to "not working" was the code re-format, I still think the likely culprit for *that* error was a function being used in a different scope than previous.